# What kinds of applications need to be multi-threaded?

Tags: multithreading

What are **some concrete examples** of applications that need to be multi-threaded, or don't need to be, but are much better that way?

Answers would be best if in the form of one application per post that way the most applicable will float to the top.

Comment: It is amazing how much I want to see this voted up to 10.  It just goes to show that this silly badge/reputation system really is warping my mind.

Comment: Is it too much to beg for an upvote?

Comment: This is definitely "Too broad". But I'm not close voting because I want to know it! :-)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is no hard and fast answer, but most of the time you will not see any advantage for systems where the workflow/calculation is sequential.  If however the problem can be broken down into tasks that can be run in parallel (or the problem itself is massively parallel [as some mathematics or analytical problems are]), you can see large improvements.

If your target hardware is single processor/core, you're unlikely to see any improvement with multi-threaded solutions (as there is only one thread at a time run anyway!)

Writing multi-threaded code is often harder as you may have to invest time in creating thread management logic.

Some examples

- **Image processing** can often be done in parallel (e.g. split the image into 4 and do the work in 1/4 of the time) but it depends upon the algorithm being run to see if that makes sense.
- **Rendering of animation** (from 3DMax,etc.) is massively parallel as each frame can be rendered independently to others -- meaning that 10's or 100's of computers can be chained together to help out.
- **GUI** programming often helps to have at least two threads when doing something slow, e.g. processing large number of files - this allows the interface to remain responsive whilst the worker does the hard work (in C# the BackgroundWorker is an example of this)

GUI's are an interesting area as the "responsiveness" of the interface can be maintained without multi-threading if the worker algorithm keeps the main GUI "alive" by giving it time, in Windows API terms (before .NET, etc) this could be achieved by a primitive loop and no need for threading:

```
MSG msg;
while(GetMessage(&msg, hwnd, 0, 0))
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);

    // do some stuff here and then release, the loop will come back
    // almost immediately (unless the user has quit)
}
```

Comment: even on a single-core system, multithreaded code can result in considerable performance improvements when there is a task that is bot CPU- and IO-intensive, i.e. with a single thread the CPU would sometimes be idle while the thread does IO.

Comment: Why did you not mention IO? Threading is in many cases an optimal solution for massively io bound applications (such as os kernels for example)

Answer (score 15):

*Servers* are typically multi-threaded (web servers, radius servers, email servers, any server): you usually want to be able to handle multiple requests simultaneously.  If you do not want to wait for a request to end before you start to handle a new request, then you mainly have two options:

1. Run a process with multiple threads
2. Run multiple processes

Launching a process is usually more resource-intensive than lauching a thread (or picking one in a thread-pool), so servers are usually multi-threaded.  Moreover, threads can communicate directly since they share the same memory space.

The problem with multiple threads is that they are usually harder to code right than multiple processes.

Comment: These days, another option is becoming rather popular: asynchronous or non-blocking I/O. This, of course, assumes you're I/O bound rather than CPU bound.

Answer (score 8):

There are really three classes of reasons that multithreading would be applied:

- **Execution Concurrency to improve compute performance**: If you have a problem that can be broken down into pieces and you also have more than one execution unit (processor core) available then dispatching the pieces into separate threads is the path to being able to simultaneously use two or more cores at once.
- **Concurrency of CPU and IO Operations**: This is similar in thinking to the first one but in this case the objective is to keep the CPU busy AND also IO operations (ie: disk I/O) moving in parallel rather than alternating between them.
- **Program Design and Responsiveness**: Many types of programs can take advantage of threading as a program design benefit to make the program more responsive to the user. For example the program can be interacting via the GUI and also doing something in the background.

Concrete Examples:

- **Microsoft Word**: Edit document while the background grammar and spell checker works to add all the green and red squiggle underlines.
- **Microsoft Excel**: Automatic background recalculations after cell edits
- **Web Browser**: Dispatch multiple threads to load each of the several HTML references in parallel during a single page load. Speeds page loads and maximizes TCP/IP data throughput.

Answer (score 5):

These days, the answer should be **Any application that can be**.

The speed of execution for a single thread pretty much peaked years ago - processors have been getting faster by adding cores, not by increasing clock speeds.  There have been some architectural improvements that make better use of the available clock cycles, but really, the future is taking advantage of threading.

There is a ton of research going on into finding ways of parallelizing activities that we traditionally wouldn't think of parallelizing.  Even something as simple as finding a substring within a string can be parallelized.

Answer (score 4):

Basically there are two reasons to multi-thread:

1. To be able to do processing tasks in parallel.  This only applies if you have multiple cores/processors, otherwise on a single core/processor computer you will slow the task down compared to the version without threads.
2. I/O whether that be networked I/O or file I/O.  Normally if you call a blocking I/O call, the process has to wait for the call to complete.  Since the processor/memory are several orders of magnitude quicker than a disk drive (and a network is even slower) it means the processor will be waiting a long time.  The computer will be working on other things but your application will not be making any progress.  However if you have multiple threads, the computer will schedule your application and the other threads can execute.  One common use is a GUI application.  Then while the application is doing I/O the GUI thread can keep refreshing the screen without looking like the app is frozen or not responding.  Even on a single processor putting I/O in a different thread will tend to speed up the application.

The single threaded alternative to 2 is to use asynchronous calls where they return immediately and you keep controlling your program.  Then you have to see when the I/O completes and manage using it.  It is often simpler just to use a thread to do the I/O using the synchronous calls as they tend to be easier.

The reason to use threads instead of separate processes is because threads should be able to share data easier than multiple processes.  And sometimes switching between threads is less expensive than switching between processes.

As another note, for #1 Python threads won't work because in Python only one python instruction can be executed at a time (known as the GIL or Global Interpreter Lock).  I use that as an example but you need to check around your language.  In python if you want to do parallel calculations, you need to do separate processes.

Answer (score 3):

Many GUI frameworks are multi-threaded.  This allows you to have a more responsive interface.  For example, you can click on a "Cancel" button at any time while a long calculation is running.

Note that there are other solutions for this (for example the program can pause the calculation every half-a-second to check whether you clicked on the Cancel button or not), but they do not offer the same level of responsiveness (the GUI might seem to freeze for a few seconds while a file is being read or a calculation being done).

Comment: Actually I would say, that it is the other way around. Many GUI frameworks are single threaded in the sense, that the GUI itself only supports one thread. So if you want to do anything and still leave the GUI free to process GUI messages, you need additional threads.

Answer (score 3):

All the answers so far are focusing on the fact that multi-threading or multi-processing are necessary to make the best use of modern hardware.

There is however also the fact that multithreading can make life much easier for the programmer. At work I program software to control manufacturing and testing equipment, where a single machine often consists of several positions that work in parallel. Using multiple threads for that kind of software is a natural fit, as the parallel threads model the physical reality quite well. The threads do mostly not need to exchange any data, so the need to synchronize threads is rare, and many of the reasons for multithreading being difficult do therefore not apply.

**Edit:**

This is not really about a performance improvement, as the (maybe 5, maybe 10) threads are all mostly sleeping. It is however a huge improvement for the program structure when the various parallel processes can be coded as sequences of actions that do not know of each other. I have very bad memories from the times of 16 bit Windows, when I would create a state machine for each machine position, make sure that nothing would take longer than a few milliseconds, and constantly pass the control to the next state machine. When there were hardware events that needed to be serviced on time, and also computations that took a while (like FFT), then things would get ugly real fast.

Comment: Yes - a good add and I agree with the premise. Although in the end, this technique really is performance improvement in that this is the practical path to keeping the CPU busy more of the time. In any case, +1 vote.

Answer (score 2):

Not directly answering your question, I believe in the very near future, almost every application will need to be multithreaded. The CPU performance is not growing that fast these days, which is compensated for by **the increasing number of cores**. Thus, if we will want our applications to stay on the top performance-wise, we'll need to find ways to utilize all your computer's CPUs and keep them busy, which is quite a hard job.

This can be done via telling your programs what to do instead of telling them exactly how. Now, this is a topic I personally find very interesting recently. Some functional languages, like F#, are able to parallelize many tasks quite easily. Well, not THAT easily, but still without the necessary infrastructure needed in more procedural-style environments.

Please take this as additional information to think about, not an attempt to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

The kind of applications that ***need*** to be threaded are the ones where you want to do more than one thing at once. Other than that no application needs to be multi-threaded.

Answer (score 1):

Applications with a large workload which can be easily made parallel. The difficulty of taking your application and doing that should not be underestimated. It is easy when your data you're manipulating is not dependent upon other data but v. hard to schedule the cross thread work when there is a dependency.

Some examples I've done which are good multithreaded candidates..

- running scenarios (eg stock derivative pricing, statistics)
- bulk updating data files (eg adding a value / entry to 10,000 records)
- other mathematical processes

Answer (score 0):

E.g., you want your programs to be multithreaded when you want to utilize multiple cores and/or CPUs, even when the programs don't *necessarily* do many things at the same time.

EDIT: using multiple processes is the same thing. Which technique to use depends on the platform and how you are going to do communications within your program, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Although frivolous, games, in general are becomming more and more threaded every year. At work our game uses around 10 threads doing physics, AI, animation, redering, network and IO.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to add that caution must be taken with treads if your sharing any resources as this can lead to some very strange behavior, and your code not working correctly or even the threads locking each other out.

mutex will help you there as you can use mutex locks for protected code regions, a example of protected code regions would be reading or writing to shared memory between threads.

just my 2 cents worth.

Comment: You don't lock code. You lock data. Locking code is bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

The main purpose of multithreading is *to separate time domains*. So the uses are everywhere where you want several things to happen in their own distinctly separate time domains.

Answer (score 0):

HERE IS A PERFECT USE CASE

If you like affiliate marketing multi-threading is essential. Kick the entire process off via a multi-threaded application.

Download merchant files via FTP, unzipping the files, enumerating through each file performing cleanup like EOL terminators from Unix to PC CRLF then slam each into SQL Server via Bulk Inserts then when all threads are complete create the full text search indexes for a environmental instance to be live tomorrow and your done.  All automated to kick off at say 11:00 pm.

BOOM! Fast as lightening.  Heck you have so much time left you can even download merchant images locally for the products you download, save the images as webp and set the product urls to use local images.

Yep I did it.  Wrote it in C#.  Works like a charm.  Purchase a AMD Ryzen Threadripper 64-core with 256gb memory and fast drives like nvme, get lunch come back and see it all done or just stay around and watch all cores peg to 95%+, listen to the pc's fans kick, warm up the room and the look outside as the neighbors lights flicker from the power drain as you get shit done.

Future would be to push processing to GPU's as well.

Ok well I am pushing it a little bit with the neighbors lights flickering but all else was absolutely true.  :)